# Unable to invoke REST service using Shell Script - [ CLOSED ]

Tags: shell

I have a REST service and trying to invoke through SHELL script but It throws below error message.

> curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

I have the below Test.sh file that will try to invoke the REST service:

```
    test="$(cat testng-results.xml)"
    test1="$(cat testng-results_1.xml)"
    echo "$test"
    echo"http://10.239.61.4:8083/testngXML/getTestNGMerge/${test}/originalXML/${test1}"
    curl -O --globoff -X GET "http://10.239.61.4:8083/testngXML/getTestNGMerge/${test}/originalXML/${test1}"
```

I'm trying to pass the XML content as query parameter in the end URL because I have rest client deployed in different host and accessing the shell script in different host that's the reason passing the XML content as REST end point URL.

how to make it the above REST url to work, and Is it right way to do that and if its not then which is the best way to do that

**testNG-Result.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
    <suite name="TransferMoney-Suite" duration-ms="157605" started-at="2018-11-14T04:34:27Z" finished-at="2018-11-14T04:37:05Z"> 
  <test name="TransferMoneyTest" duration-ms="153141" started-at="2018-11-14T04:34:27Z" finished-at="2018-11-14T04:37:01Z"> 
    <class name="com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.transfermoney.TransferMoneyMillenniumE2ETest"> 
      <test-method status="PASS" signature="initializeDataProvider(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.transfermoney.TransferMoneyMillenniumE2ETest@3168e461]" name="initializeDataProvider" is-config="true" duration-ms="27" started-at="2018-11-13T20:34:30Z" finished-at="2018-11-13T20:34:30Z"> 
        <params> 
          <param index="0"> 
            <value>35,</value> 
          </param>  
          <param index="1"> 
            <value is-null="true"/> 
          </param>  
          <param index="2"> 
            <value is-null="true"/> 
          </param> 
        </params> 
      </test-method>  
      <!-- initializeDataProvider -->  
      <!-- transferMoneyPaymentE2ETest --> 
    </class>  
    <!-- com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.transfermoney.TransferMoneyMillenniumE2ETest --> 
  </test>  
  <!-- TransferMoneyTest -->  
  <test name="Suite setup and teardown" duration-ms="4312" started-at="2018-11-14T04:37:01Z" finished-at="2018-11-14T04:37:05Z"> 
    <class name="com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite"> 
      <test-method status="FAIL" signature="suiteSetup(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite@681da322]" name="suiteSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="56" started-at="2018-11-13T20:34:27Z" finished-at="2018-11-13T20:34:27Z"> 
        <params> 
          <param index="0"> 
            <value>org.testng.TestRunner@74bc72e0</value> 
          </param> 
        </params> 
      </test-method>  
      <!-- suiteSetup -->  
      <test-method status="PASS" signature="dumpTransactionInfo()[pri:0, instance:com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite@681da322]" name="dumpTransactionInfo" is-config="true" duration-ms="23" started-at="2018-11-13T20:37:05Z" finished-at="2018-11-13T20:37:05Z"/>  
      <!-- dumpTransactionInfo --> 
    </class>  
    <!-- com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite --> 
  </test>  
  <!-- Suite setup and teardown --> 
</suite>
</testng-results>
```

**TestNG-Result_1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
    <suite name="TransferMoney-Suite" duration-ms="157605" started-at="2018-11-14T04:34:27Z" finished-at="2018-11-14T04:37:05Z"> 
  <test name="TransferMoneyTest" duration-ms="153141" started-at="2018-11-14T04:34:27Z" finished-at="2018-11-14T04:37:01Z"> 
    <class name="com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.transfermoney.TransferMoneyMillenniumE2ETest"> 
      <test-method status="PASS" signature="initializeDataProvider(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.transfermoney.TransferMoneyMillenniumE2ETest@3168e461]" name="initializeDataProvider" is-config="true" duration-ms="27" started-at="2018-11-13T20:34:30Z" finished-at="2018-11-13T20:34:30Z"> 
        <params> 
          <param index="0"> 
            <value>35,</value> 
          </param>  
          <param index="1"> 
            <value is-null="true"/> 
          </param>  
          <param index="2"> 
            <value is-null="true"/> 
          </param> 
        </params> 
      </test-method>  
      <!-- initializeDataProvider -->  
      <!-- transferMoneyPaymentE2ETest --> 
    </class>  
    <!-- com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.transfermoney.TransferMoneyMillenniumE2ETest --> 
  </test>  
  <!-- TransferMoneyTest -->  
  <test name="Suite setup and teardown" duration-ms="4312" started-at="2018-11-14T04:37:01Z" finished-at="2018-11-14T04:37:05Z"> 
    <class name="com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite"> 
      <test-method status="FAIL" signature="suiteSetup(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite@681da322]" name="suiteSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="56" started-at="2018-11-13T20:34:27Z" finished-at="2018-11-13T20:34:27Z"> 
        <params> 
          <param index="0"> 
            <value>org.testng.TestRunner@74bc72e0</value> 
          </param> 
        </params> 
      </test-method>  
      <!-- suiteSetup -->  
      <test-method status="PASS" signature="dumpTransactionInfo()[pri:0, instance:com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite@681da322]" name="dumpTransactionInfo" is-config="true" duration-ms="23" started-at="2018-11-13T20:37:05Z" finished-at="2018-11-13T20:37:05Z"/>  
      <!-- dumpTransactionInfo --> 
    </class>  
    <!-- com.paypal.test.e2e.millennium.settlement.SettlementE2ESuite --> 
  </test>  
  <!-- Suite setup and teardown --> 
</suite>
</testng-results>
```

Comment: I don't know how the REST API you're programming against works, but it looks very weird to put the XML data into the URL like that. Normally I'd expect you to POST the XML as data, instead of GETting it as part of the URL.

Comment: is this your api? You should really send this payload through a POST call body, not in the URL itself. This sounds like a totally bad practice, but lets say that its your app and you really want to do it this way, then modify your app to receive  the payload in the URL but ENCODED in base64. That would get rid of the error if your app is smart enough to decode it on the other end. Anyway, I repeat, this sounds like a bad practice.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments - XML in the body of a POST is a cleaner way to go.  As you have found out, you can't pass XML in the URL.  You'll need to encode it - since there are some characters that are not permitted in a URL.  You'll need to take a look at URL encoding.

Comment: I'm closing this ticket since many of you told its bad practice. I had scenario like that I need to merge two XML with original one. I don't think so it could be done through XML body. I will try someother way to solve this. Thanks for your inputs it really helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is bad practice and not advisable so closing this question.